# Running ARM64 Android on ARM64

Tags: android-emulator, arm-processors

I have a Linux ARM64 *computer* (not phone). How can I use this to run an ARM64 Android phone image?

[Android Studio does not work on ARM64 computers](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux). Android Studio with emulator works on x86. I do not want to use ARM64 to emulate x86 to run the x86 Android image since it is unusably slow.

Comment: [Waydroid](https://waydro.id/#cpus1) is one of the options.

Comment: @IrfanLatif do you have more detailed steps to run/install it? [Following the steps](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops#ubuntu-debian-and-derivatives), I am stuck on the last one: `Waiting for waydroid container service...
Failed to load binder driver
modprobe: FATAL: Module binder_linux not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0
Binder node "binder" for waydroid not found`. Is patching the kernel with `binder` module safe?